# Using Binomial Distribution for analysis

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ such that $p>\frac{1}{2}$.
I know that $\forall k\in \{1\cdots n\}$ the following holds:
$Pr(x\geq k)= \sum_{t=k}^n {{n}\choose{t}} p^t (1-p)^{(n-t)}$

But is there a way to simplify this expression further? so I can loose the $\sum$? or at least approximate\bound it? What about the special case where $k=\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: Don't think there exists a simpler closed form for this. However, many programming languages already implement it. See for instance the `pbinom` function of the R language.

Comment: Thanks, I need it for mathematical analysis, not to implement it in a software, even though I love R! . I am looking for a good approximation or a closed form bound....

Comment: It can also be expressed in terms of the incomplete beta function, but don't think it changes that much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approximation which works reasonably well for large $n$ and reasonable $k$ is a Gaussian approximation with a continuity correction, in effect an application of the Central Limit Theorem.  This gives reasonable absolute errors, but poor relative errors in the tails (Chernoff bounds work better in the tails)

This would suggest

$$\displaystyle \sum_{t=k}^n {{n}\choose{t}} p^t (1-p)^{(n-t)} \approx \Phi\left(\dfrac{np-k+\tfrac12}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \right)$$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution

As an example, let $p=\frac23$, $n=50$ and $k=35$. Using R, the exact sum is

```
> sum( choose(50, 35:50) * (2/3)^(35:50) * (1/3)^(15:0) )
[1] 0.3689669
```

while the approximation would give

```
> pnorm( (50*2/3 - 35 + 1/2) / sqrt(50*2/3*(1-2/3)) ) 
[1] 0.3631693
```

though if you have R you can just use `pbinom(35-1, size=50, prob=2/3, lower.tail = FALSE)` as a clearer way of getting to the exact result